# How to edit config files in react-create-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I want to use some third-party packages upon react, which are:

- https://ant.design/ - a design system
- https://github.com/vazco/uniforms - for generating and validating forms.

I am using create-react-app for as a boilerplate

After installing all packages (with yarn) and running `yart start` I am getting this error:

[image]

How can I add  `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`  without running `yarn eject` to modify `.babelrc` file?

Or is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way is to eject.  CRA has purposely avoided too much customization.  See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/167